# Dynamic value for path in <form:input > to map with object attribute in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to access model class variable by creating dynamic string.
Below is the code snippet.

```
<form:input path="${accountType.field}.name.firstName" />
```

The required output would be: `direct.name.firstName` or `indirect.name.firstname`

```
Account direct;
Account indirect;
```

Both fields are available in model.

I am getting error by above method, it seems the code `${accountType.field}` is getting compiled first and gives error.

> Error: Bean property ' ' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does
>   the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

It is working perfect if i write hard code value like this.

```
<form:input path="direct.name.firstName" />
```

Please suggest me how to resolve this.

Comment: what error you get ...?

Comment: @libik I have updated the error in above post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind using name value pair instead of path.
Change your html element with

```
<form id="myId">
    <input name="${accountType.field}.name.firstName" value=""/>
</form>
```

and post this form

Comment: Thanks @Navish, i solved this using plain html by this line.   **<input name="${accountType.field}.name.firstName" value="${accountType.name.firstName}"/>**

Comment: This answer will not use spring specific form

Comment: Ok.. @ShoaibChikate, could you please provide me any other solution?